# Possible to host desktop application C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cloud

My boss wants to show a desktop application using C# for a new customer, I'm wondering if there is a way to use cloud services or another method to host the application to be tested by the customer.

Cordially

Comment: Send him the .exe? Or at worst do a remote desktop session.

Comment: *Your bug is at line 237*. If this comment doesn't make any sense, read what/how to ask a question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy it to AWS (Amazon Cloud). Use Citrix XenApp or AWS has Citrix XenApp AMI's in its marketplace. You can host your C#.net windows app on Amazon EC2. Install Citrix XenApp on AWS and deliver your desktop app to your customer via Xenapp.